# How do you combine the weak models in gradient boosted tree?

Tags: boosting, boosted-regression-trees

In this article
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/11/quick-introduction-boosting-algorithms-machine-learning/

The author indicates you combine 3 weak models into a final one using gradient boosting, but gave no detail how to combine them. Could someone explain how that's done?

Comment: No. The article does give you explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The author explicitly state the three algorithms which combine weak learners to a more powerfull boosted model; AdaBoost, GradientBoosting and XGBoost with the python codes relevant to each boosting. XGboost is in his next article.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the result is weighted average of the weak learners, where the weight is the same as the learning rate.

[image]